# ServiceNotAvailableError: Failed to register SAAgent

Tags: samsung-mobile, tizen, accessory, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'm developing an integrated Gear 2 App and I have some issues with the connection between the phone and Gear 2. The problem is when I call the function:

```js
webapis.sa.requestSAAgent(onsuccess, onerror);
```

In the console I have this log: `ONERROR: err [ServiceNotAvailableError] msg [Failed to register SAAgent.]`

The problem is that the functions instantly go to the `onerror` function, jumping the `onsucces` function. I post my code for clarification:

```js
function onerror (err) {
    console.log("ONERROR: err [" + err.name + "] msg [" + err.message + "]");
}

var agentCallBack = {
onconnect: function (socket) {
    console.log ("agentCallBack onconnect" + socket);
    SASocket = socket;
    alert("SAP Connection Establishe with RemotePeer");
    createHTML("startConnection");
    SASocket.setSocketStatusListener(function(reason) {
        console.log ("Service connection lost, Reason: [" + reason + "]");
        disconnect();
    })
},
onerror : onerror
};

var peerAgentFindCallback = {
onpeeragentfound : function(peerAgent) {
    try {
        if (peerAgent.appName == ProviderAppName) {
            SAAgent.setServiceConnectionListener(agentCallback);
            SAAgent.requestServiceConnection(peerAgent);
        } else {
            alert("Not expected app!! : " + peerAgent.appName);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("exception [" + err.name + "] msg[" + err.message + "]");
    }
},
onerror : onerror
}

function onsuccess(agents) {
try {
    if (agents.length > 0) {
        SAAgent = agents[0];

        SAAgent.setPeerAgentFindListener(peerAgentFindCallback);
        SAAgent.findPeerAgents();
    } else {
        alert("Not found SAAgent!!");
    }
} catch(err) {
    console.log("exception [" + err.name + "] msg[" + err.message + "]");
}
}
```

Anyone can explain how can I fix this? I've already put this privilege into the `config.xml` file:

```xml
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/accessoryprotocol"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you are missing serviceprofile.xml file. You need that in both phone and gear applications.
Here is samsung developer guide: http://pl.scribd.com/doc/231769842/Samsung-Gear-Application-Getting-Started-1-0
Look into section 5.2.